# Combine results from a foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have this array that i'm running a foreach loop to him and can't possible figure out how i can display the results combined.

Array
(

```
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [title] => main
        [url] => url1
        [value] => value1
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [title] => second
        [url] => url2
        [value] => value2
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [title] => other
        [url] => url3
        [value] => value3
    )
[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [title] => other
        [url] => url4
        [value] => value4
    )
```

)

I want to specify this is just an example so the array isn't sorted. Unless i could sort to put title->main first and title->second - 2nd position?

I need to display something like: `<a href=" url1 (from title=>main) "> value2 (from title=>second) </a>`

Any help is really appreciated!! Thank you very much!!

Marius

Answer (score 2):

assuming your array is named $objects

```
foreach ( $objects as $obj )
{
    echo "<a href='$obj->url1'> (from $obj->title)  $obj->value </a>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please elaborate a bit more. What I can say about this now is that you could;

```
<a href="<?php echo $var[0]->url; ?>"> <?php echo $var[1]->title; ?> </a>
```

But this probably isn't what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! The results are not always sorted, so using 0, 1, 2 etc isn't the solution, unless the whole array is sorted by the title value, putting title->main first and title->second - second?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
$count = count($array) - 1;

for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    echo '<a href="'.$array[$i]->url.'">'.$array[$i + 1]->title.'</a>';
}
```

Comment: this will cause the last index to be out of bounds.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! The results are not always sorted, so using 0, 1, 2 etc isn't the solution, unless the whole array is sorted by the title value, putting title->main first and title->second - second?

Comment: @davogotland thanks I've fixed it


how should it be sorted, alphabetically by the title attribute? If there is a definite routine that needs to be executed on each call we can get a solution!